# C#/Xamarin bug? Booleans

Tags: c#, xamarin

This is weird. I have this C# code:

```
bool value = (((Literal)expr.left).value == ((Literal)expr.right).value);
```

When I inspect it with the Xamarin debugger, it tells me `value` is `false`, but `(((Literal)expr.left).value == ((Literal)expr.right).value)` is `true`. Why is that? I'm so confused...

Comment: Are you sure you inspected it after this line of code executed?

Comment: Are you inspecting it before or after that line is evaluated and the value assigned?  It's *highly unlikely* that C# and/or Xamarin has a bug which confuses `true` with `false`.  Something like that would be noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. `((Literal)expr.left).value` is an `object`, which means this always will return false unless right and left are *the same* bool, which they're not.

Casting them both to bool will compare their value instead.

```
bool value = ((bool)((Literal)expr.left).value == (bool)((Literal)expr.right).value);
```

Comment: You also could use `.Equals (` instead of `==` and not cast.